# What is the Tibco stack

Tags: soa, business-process-management, tibco, complex-event-processing

I will be using tibco, I am confused on the technical stack of it.

BPM Engine - TIBCO iProcess
   |
CEP Engine - TIBCO Business Events
   |
TIBCO ActiveSpaces

Is this correct? Where would BusinessWorks comes in?

Comment: The TIBCO stack can be confusing and intimidating and without proper exposure it is not at all obvious what the actual technical components look like at run-time, nor what they might correspond to in other platforms.  Unfortunately the TIBCO website often seems richer in marketing material than technical details.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to get your description of the TIBCO stack would be the [TIBCO Product Index](https://www.tibco.com/products)

Click through each and go through their two minute videos (links on the right side) to get a basic overview.

To answer your questions,

Yes, they have
  BPM - in iProcess, Business Studio
  CEP - using TIBCO Business Events
  EAI - Application Integration - using ActiveMatrix (AMX) products which includes Business Works
  ESB - Message buses like EMS, RV

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question about ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks (BW):

BusinessWorks encompasses a series of technologies which together provide a comprehensive Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) platform.

BusinessWorks Designer provides a 5GL development GUI allowing integration developers and architects to model, design, implement and test end-to-end integrations.  The toolset provides an extremely comprehensive set of capabilities to integrate with major database platforms either via adapters or JDBC, web services, Java Messaging Services (JMS), and many others.  Transformations and logic are implemented primarily via "mappers" which are implemented using XSLT and/or XPATH.

BusinessWorks (BW) defines processes which are then run as jobs.  These are run within a Java VM context in BWEngine run-times similar to ASP.NET worker processes.

The central server which manages and marshals BW messages is either Enterprise Message Service (EMS, a JMS based messaging server) or Rendezvous (a TIBCO proprietary peer-to-peer messaging platform which predates JMS).  In addition, a seperate BW server (which may or may not leverage Hawk monitoring) schedules and controls the various BW processes/programs (which can run across distributed hardware).

All of this runs in the context of a TIBCO domain which is typically controlled by an EMS server.

The TIBCO family of products has various degrees of interop.  It is a fair assessment to consider ActiveMatrix BW as the backbone upon which many of the other products rely.